# React&Typescript Exclude from interface definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definition

after many hours of test i ask you. i want define my interface object

```
export interface OptionPros {
    text: string;
    color?: string|undefined;
    fontStyle?: string|undefined;
    sidePadding?: number|undefined;
}
```

after, i will want create a type that use only "text" property, the other are optional.

```
type OO=Exclude<"color"|"fontStyle"|"sidePadding", OptionPros>
```

now it's all ok, but whe i try use this definition in props of my class react

**file1.tsx**

```
export interface OptionPros {
    text: string;
    color?: string|undefined;
    fontStyle?: string|undefined;
    sidePadding?: number|undefined;
}
type OO=Exclude<"color"|"fontStyle"|"sidePadding", OptionPros>

export interface DProps extends BaseProps {
    optionD: OO
}
export default class DDD <DProps> {
    static defaultProps = {
        optionD: {
            text: '',
            color: '#FF6384', // Default is #000000
            fontStyle: 'Arial', // Default is Arial
            sidePadding: 20 // Defualt is 20 (as a percentage)
        }
    };
    render() {<div>AAAA</div>}
 }
```

**file2.tsx**

```
 //i omit react and other inclusion or extension
 import.....
 export default class AAAA {
 render() {return(<DDD optionD={{text:"hello world"}}>AAAA</DDD >)}
```

and i have this messagge error

**Type '{ text: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ text: string; color: string; fontStyle: string; sidePadding: number; }'.
  Property 'color' is missing in type '{ text: string; }'.**

i can not understand why? i use typescript > 2.8 anche the ts documentation it's not very clear. Can someone help me to resolved and undestand my errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've succeeded in reproducing the error.  Your component declaration should be:

```
export default class DDD extends React.Component<DProps> { ... }
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And if you want to exclude the `color`, `fontStyle`, and `sidePadding` properties from `OptionPros`, what you need is not `Exclude` (which just excludes one type from another) but the operation more commonly called `Omit`, defined and used as follows:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type OO=Omit<OptionPros, "color"|"fontStyle"|"sidePadding">
```

With these changes, I am no longer getting the error.

Comment: Thanks Matt,but Pick what is?can you give me the url for exact reading to understand T,K e PIck

Comment: There's some documentation of the "utility types" [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Utility%20Types.md).  This page was recently added and I expect it will be deployed to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook eventually.  For further background on how these types are defined, see [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types).